# Is Recaptcha really needed to prevent bots attack in your Sitecore forms SXA 9.3?

Tags: sitecore-forms

Is Recaptcha really needed to prevent bots attack in your Sitecore forms SXA 9.3?  My need is I want to prevent bot attack in my website. I have a sitecore form which is capturing user email. Do I really need Recaptcha or Sitecore handles it internally?

Answer (score 3):

If you are on XP and have xDB and xDB tracking enabled, then you can enable robot detection on your your forms. But, this will not protect against replay attacks.

The robot detection will filter out unwanted interactions from bots and ensure that only genuine contacts are registered in xDB.

If you want to have similar protection levels on your forms that a recaptcha provides, then you will need to add a recaptcha.

references:

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/103/sitecore-experience-platform/work-with-robot-detection-for-forms.html
- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/robot-detection-overview.html

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes. Generally speaking, if a public site has a form on it, bot traffic will eventually zero in on it and hammer away. In my opinion, if you have forms on your site, you will want all of the following:

- Web Application Firewall (WAF) to detect and block bots and to give you the ability to specify additional checks and handling for form page / POST request endpoints.
- Client side validation.
- Server side validation (which includes reCAPTCHA or something similar such as Cloudflare Turnstile). Honeypots are no good; bots easily bypass them.

I recommend implementing these security measures from day 1 of launch, if possible. Bots discover these pages and endpoints by crawling your site. If you prevent bots from discovering forms in the first place, you will have fewer issues in the future.